# Golang REST API: Security checks?

Tags: web-application, account-security, rest

It's my first time building and deploying a REST API with just the standard library. Are there any gotchas I should keep an eye out for regarding securing my REST API?

Comment: If you look in the "Related" section on the side, you will see multiple questions here about securing REST APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the list of best practices in securing RESTful API.

1. Always Use HTTPS - Traffic must be encrypted
2. Never expose information on URLs - as this can be captured in web server logs, which makes them easily exploitable.

   `https://api.domain.com/user-management/users/{id}/someAction?apiKey=abcd123456789`
3. Consider [Oauth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
4. Adding Timestamp in Request - This will prevent very basic replay attacks from people who are trying to brute force your system
5. Input Parameter Validation - Put strong validation checks and reject the request immediately if validation fails.
6. Use Auditing and Logging - Any subject or entity can be audited

For more information, OWASP Provide a cheatsheet found [here.](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html)